# Does Stack Overflow have an "echo page" to test AJAX requests, inside a code snippet?

Tags: support, feature-request, stack-snippets

Stack Overflow allows you to [insert code snippets](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) both in question and answer's bodies.

Does it provide a way to test AJAX requests in a way similar to [what jsfiddle does](http://jsfiddle.net/L6bJ2/6/) ([docs](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html))? It provides an echo page, that send back anything sent to it:

```js
$(function() {

    $('.document').on('click', '.ajax', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        // ajax request
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            type: 'post',
            url: '/echo/html/',
            data: {
                html: '<p>This is echoed the response in HTML format</p>',
                delay: 1
            },
            dataType: 'html',
            beforeSend: function() {
                console.log('Fired prior to the request');
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log('Fired when the request is successfull');
                $('.document').append(data);
            },
            complete: function() {
                console.log('Fired when the request is complete');
            }
        });

    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="document">
<a class="ajax" href="#">Fire an AJAX request</a>
</div>
```

If you try the snippet, you can see that it does not return the echoed response, but the jsfiddle above does; the output should be (if you clicked on "Fire an AJAX request"):

> Fire an AJAX request 
> This is echoed the response in HTML format

If not, are there reliable alternatives... I mean echo pages that are CORS enabled, and that we can rely.

P.S. I know I can do it in jsFiddle, and just use that instead... but I like Stack Overflow snippets, and wanted to know if I can make these AJAX samples inside the Stack Overflow snippet.

Comment: If the answer is no, can this be a [meta-tag:feature-request]?

Comment: <?php
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
var_dump('$_GET',$_GET,'$_POST',$_POST,'$_COOKIE',$_COOKIE,'$_FILES',$_FILES);
?> https://gist.github.com/divinity76/b25b1ecea9c5f08f1a1f

Comment: The whole snippets feature is implemented as a giant echo server, but I couldn't get it work (I probably did something wrong, but I'm getting blocked by CORS although I POST to `.` or `js`. Either way, that is not *really* an echo, because the result is a full HTML page, and there is no `delay`.

Comment: You were most likely blocked because the sanboxed iframes do not have an *origin*. This is one of the security limitations enabled for the stack snippets. This would be an awesome feature to have, although I'm afraid that with the current method used it won't be possible. Hope we get an official statement on this. Alternatively, the server needs to accept requests from any source. Not sure if SE would want that.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Tried `js` at post ?

Comment: @guest271314 Seen it just now... it is a nice workaround. Thanks.

Comment: @robbmj I have added the tag `feature-request` as you proposed.

Comment: Interesting.
I haven't (yet) tried `https://jsfiddle.net/echo/html/`, but I suppose it does
something similar to `https://httpbin.org/post`?
I.e. offering a simple and free RESTful API for making POST requests - without
requiring any authorization?
For GET requests, I have a few favorites:
`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/2`,
`https://postman-echo.com/get`,
`http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random`,
`https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2`.
I think `https://reqres.in/` offers POST requests as well, but I haven't tried
it.

Answer (score 4):

Try utilizing [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL) .

Note,

- `cache:false` returns `XMLHttpRequest cannot load blob:null/xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx?123. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.`
- `$.post()` returns `"NetworkError: Failed to execute 'send' on 'XMLHttpRequest': 'GET' is the only method allowed for 'blob:' URLs."`

```js
var blobs = [];

var echo = function echo(data, type) {
  var blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data], {
    "type": type
  }));

  blobs.push(blob);

  return blob
};

$(document).on("click", ".ajax", function(e) {

  $.get(echo("<p>This is echoed the response in HTML format</p>", "text/html")
  , function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {
      console.log(data, textStatus, jqxhr, blobs);
      $(".document").append(data)
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button class="ajax">click</button>
<div class="document">response:
  <br />
</div>
```

---

tl;dr.

```js
// MIT license https://github.com/guest271314/echo-snippets/blob/master/LICENSE
// echo-snippet-1.1.0.js 
// Reference http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288902/

$(function() {
  // utilize `$(document)` object as `this` at `complete`,
  // `$(document).data().requestData` to log processes 
  $(document).data({
      "requestData": {
        "requests": [],
        "delay": null,
        "delayStart": null,
        "delayStop": null,
        "settings": void 0,
        // log `progress` messages , 
        "progress": function progress(msg) {
          return (function(msg) {
            if (this.delayStart === null) {
              this.delayStart = $.now();
            } else {
              this.delayStop = $.now();
            };
            console.log("processing `echo-snippet` at " 
                   + (this.delayStop === null ? this.delayStart : $.now() 
                   + " delay complete:" + (this.delayStop - this.delayStart)),
                   this,
                   msg ? msg : "progress message:" + msg + "\n")
          }).call(this, msg)
        }
      }
    })
    // do stuff at `ajaxStop`, `ajaxComplete`, `ajaxError` ,
    // when all `ajax` stuff complete
    .on("ajaxStop ajaxComplete ajaxError"
    , function(event, jqxhr, settings, errorThrown) {

      $(this).data().requestData.settings = settings;

      var type = event.type;

      var complete = $(this).dequeue("complete").promise("complete");

      // pass `jqxhr` jQuery `Promise` from `ajaxError` ,
      // `ajaxComplete` ; `ajaxStop` does not return `jqxhr` object ,
      // pass `complete` at `ajaxStop`
      // `this`:`$(document)`
      $.when.call(this, jqxhr || complete)
      .then(function response(jqxhr) {
          console.log("\n" + type, jqxhr, this);
          // `complete`
          if ($(this).is(document)) {
            console.log("\n`echo-snippet` complete at", $.now(), "\n\ndone!");
          };
        }, function error(jqxhr) {
            console.log(type, jqxhr.statusText, this)
        });

    });
  // create `blob` utilizing `window.URL.createObjectURL`
  var echo = function echo(response) {
    var blob = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([response.data], {
      "type": response.type
    }));
    // save reference to `window.URL.createObjectURL` ,
    // `cache` set to true, calling `window.URL.revokeObjectURL`
    // has no effect; though `object URL` "released" at `unload`
    // see `#Notes` at MDN `URL.createObjectURL()`
    // "Each time you call createObjectURL(), a new object URL is 
    // created, even if you've already created one for the same object.  
    // Each of these must be released by calling `URL.revokeObjectURL()` 
    // when you no longer need them. Browsers will release these 
    // automatically when the document is unloaded; 
    // however, for optimal performance and memory usage,
    // if there are safe times when you can explicitly unload them,
    // you should do so."

    // array of object URL's
    $(document).data().requestData.requests.push(blob);

    return blob
  };

  // do `ajax` request stuff
  // `args`: callback `function`; `object`; other; optional
  var request = function request(e, response, args) {
    // `e`: `event`
    if (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
    };

    try {
      if (args) {
        if (typeof args === "function") {
          args()
        } else {
          args.requestData.progress()
        }
      }
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e)
    };
    // ajax request
    return $.ajax({
      async: true,
      // cache: false,
      type: "GET",
      url: echo(response), // here is it... the echo page
      beforeSend: function(jqxhr) {
        console.log("Fired prior to the request");
        // jqxhr.abort();
      },
      success: function(data, textStatus, jqxhr) {

        console.log("Fired when the request is successfull");

        console.log(data, "\n" + textStatus
                   , "\n" + jqxhr.getAllResponseHeaders());

        $(".document").append(data);
      },
      complete: function() {
        console.log("Fired when the request is complete");
      }
    });

  };
  // set "request "`.queue()` for `delay`, 
  // set `"complete"` `.queue()` for completion of all processes
  var response = function response(res, delay, args, e) {

    var delay = delay || 0;

    $(document).data().requestData.delay = delay;

    var _res = {
      "data": res.data,
      "type": res.type
    };

    var dfd = function(e, args) {
      return $(document)
        .delay(delay, "request")
        .queue("request", function delayRequest() {
          return $.when(request(e || null, _res, args)
                        , $(this).queue("complete", $.noop))
                 
        })
        .dequeue("request")

    };
    // `dfd` `Promise`, `args` if any
    var promise = $.when(dfd, args);

    return promise
  };

  var _event = void 0;
  
  // `data`:data returned from object URL
  // `type`:`MIME type` of data
  var _echo = new response({
      "data": "<p>This is echoed the response in HTML format</p>",
      "type": "text/html"
    },
    // delay
    3500,
    // `requestData` , settings object
    $(document).data(),
    _event);

  // log message
  console.log("`echo-snippet` promise at ".concat($.now() + " :"), _echo,
    "delay:", $(document).data().requestData.delay,
    "event:", _event, "\n");

  $(document).on("click", ".ajax", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    _echo.then(function(_request, args) {
      try {
        if (args) {
          if (typeof args === "function") {
            args()
          } else {
            // pass message to `requestData.progress`
            args.requestData.progress("\n`echo-snippet` start , message at " 
                                     + $.now()  + " // do stuff");
          }
        }
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(e)
      };
      // call `request`, 
      // pass `e`:`click` `event`, `args` to `request`
      return _request(e || null, args)
      }, function(err) {
      console.log("error:", err)
    })

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<button class="ajax">click</button>
<div class="document">response:
  <br />
</div>
```

github https://github.com/guest271314/echo-snippets

Comment: Functionally, your example works great, but how would a novice understand correct AJAX coding from that example? How would they know what to include/exclude in their real-life project?

Comment: @gibberish _"How would they know what to include/exclude in their real-life project?"_ Tried example above "tl;dr." ? Which portion of `js` is not clear ? What is project attempting to accomplish ? Can provide link to project ?